# TSQL Calculate Moving Average Unit Cost (MAUC)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, window-functions

I want to calculate the [MAUC](https://docs.infor.com/ln/10.3/en-us/lnolh/help/wh/onlinemanual/000347.html) of items in the future.
Items can be components or products created from those components.
For every item I gathered a list of all planned supply (e.g. purchase orders) and demand transactions (e.g. sales orders) with their corresponding date.
For supply I have a supply price and for demand I set the column to 0.

An example of the above described data can be seen in the columns Item_ID, Date, Quantity and Unit_Value (Below is the code).
I simplified the date, because an int fulfills the same purpose as a date when it comes to ordering.

The other three columns (MAUC, Total and Stock) are the columns I want to calculate.
Stock is easy with a running sum.
The Total too is easy since it is MAUC*Stock=Total.
Only the MAUC is difficult.

Why? Because I don't want to use a `while` loop over the table and insert every line one by one.
Instead I am looking for a solution that uses `over` with aggregate and window functions.
I believe that this would be way faster than a loop.

So my goal is something like this:

```
Select 
Item_ID
, Date
, Quantity
, Unit_Value
, sum(Unit_Value) 
    over (
    Partition by Item 
    Order by Date 
    Magic with between current row and unbound preceeding
) as MAUC
From Table
```

Do you know a solution that fulfills the following criteria:

- Easy to read
- As few lines as possible
- Runs efficiently

The last one is the most important to me.

Here is the example code:

```
Create Table #test (
    Item_ID Int
    , Date Int
    , Quantity Bigint
    , Unit_Value Decimal(10,3) 
    , MAUC float
    , Total float
    , Stock Bigint
    )

Insert Into #test
values 
(1,1,10,100,100,1000,10)
, (1,2,-5,0,100,500,5)
, (1,3,-3,0,100,200,2)
, (1,4,20,120,118.181818181818,2600,22)
, (1,5,-5,0,118.181818181818,2009.09090909091,17)
, (1,6,-5,0,118.181818181818,1418.18181818182,12)
, (1,7,-5,0,118.181818181818,827.272727272727,7)
, (1,8,10,90,101.604278074866,1727.27272727273,17)
, (1,9,-2,0,101.604278074866,1524.06417112299,15)
, (1,10,-1,0,101.604278074866,1422.45989304813,14)
, (2,1,100,3,3,300,100)
, (2,2,-30,0,3,210,70)
, (2,3,-60,0,3,30,10)
, (2,4,300,2.5,2.51612903225806,780,310)
, (2,5,-100,0,2.51612903225806,528.387096774194,210)
, (2,6,-150,0,2.51612903225806,150.967741935484,60)
, (2,7,200,3.2,3.04218362282878,790.967741935484,260)
, (2,8,-30,0,3.04218362282878,699.70223325062,230)
, (2,9,-15,0,3.04218362282878,654.069478908189,215)
, (2,10,-70,0,3.04218362282878,441.116625310174,145)
```

Comment: Maybe use `avg` instead of `sum` in the window function you already provided?

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis that won't solve the problem. When there is demand the MAUC needs to be the same as was calculated when the last supply came in.

Comment: for moving average, it can't be done with a simple query as the new MAUC value is depends on it's previous value. You can use a recursive cte to compute it

Comment: @Squirrel would you recommend a CTE over using a while loop? I don't have much experience but my CTEs in the past tended to be very slow. At one point I just decided to use while loops because they were easier to understand for me.

Comment: recursive CTE is basically still a loop. You may use recursive or while loop depends on your preference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution using recursive cte

```
with
rcte as
(
    select item_ID, [Date], Quantity, Unit_Value, MAUC, Total, Stock,
           calc_mauc = convert(float, Unit_Value)
    from   #test
    where  [Date] = 1

    union all

    select t.item_ID, t.[Date], t.Quantity, t.Unit_Value, t.MAUC, t.Total, t.Stock,
           calc_mauc = case when t.Quantity > 0
                            then convert(float, ((t.Quantity * t.Unit_Value) + r.Total) 
                                              / nullif(r.Stock + t.Quantity, 0))
                            else r.calc_mauc
                            end
    from   #test t
           inner join rcte r on  t.item_ID = r.item_ID
                             and t.[Date]  = r.[Date] + 1
)
select *
from   rcte
order by item_ID, Date
```

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/d_bFb6BV)

Note : I get slight different result, you might want to verify the result and the formula for calculation

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. 
Your CTE solves the general problem. Since you said that this problem is not solvable without a CTE or a loop I will accept this answer as the solution for my question. 
When I run your code on our database I get exactly the result I expected.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, just go classic with the average:

```
Select 
  Item_ID
, Date
, Quantity
, Unit_Value
, sum(Unit_Value) over (Partition by Item_ID Order by Date rows between unbounded preceding and current row ) 
 /sum(Quantity)   over (Partition by Item_ID Order by Date rows between unbounded preceding and current row ) 
as MAUC
From #test
```

and since you like clarity, from version 2022 you can DRY the window:

```
Select 
  ...
, sum(Unit_Value) over wmauc /sum(Quantity)   over wmauc as MAUC
From #test
window wmauc as (Partition by Item_ID Order by Date rows between unbounded preceding and current row )
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. I ran your code and it does not result in the required table. You need to consider that the Unit Value for demand (negative Quantity) is not available. It needs to be calculated somehow.

Comment: ah, so negative qty means unit value is the most recent?

Comment: Yes, if the quantity is negative the MAUC stays the same as the one calculated when the last supply came in.

Comment: It stays the same? it is not reduced? So you can just `where`-off those rows?

Comment: But then you are left with the problem that the demand still lowers the amount of stock you have in the warehouse. If you where-off those rows you are calculate the stock value correctly.